# GIF file breaking Import

Tags: import, image

I'm working with a large number of historical image files and am playing around with extracting dominant colours, faces, etc. with *Mathematica 10*. Occasionally, however, I am running into files that just plain out break the language - i.e. even `Import[file,"Elements"]` leads me to have to quit the kernel to get things going again.

Here's the workflow.

Often `Import[file]` will return

> > Import::fmterr : Cannot import data as GIF format.>>

So far so good.

But if you run it *again*, the whole kernel comes crashing down. Even if I decide not to run it again, things become unstable and the program begins to hang. The same context happens with `Import[file,"Elements"]` so I'm at a loss of how to debug it.

Is there any way to get *Mathematica* to skip these files - or any clue of what might be happening?

File here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7x5qxlp6ybiqbxu/broken-image.gif

Screenshot of file in OS X preview:

[image]

In case it helps, here's the overall context of what I'm doing:

```
SetDirectory["/volumes/lacie/geocities-images/athens/"];
files = FileNames["*.*"];
hue = Reap[
   Do[input = Import[files[[x]]]; 
    Sow[If[Length[input] == 0, ImageMeasurements[input, "Mean"], 
      ImageMeasurements[input[[1]], "Mean"]]], {x, 1, 
     Length[files]}]];
```

This crashes when it hits the 'broken-image' GIF and needs to be restarted.

Comment: One workaround is to just run a bash script - `for a in *.gif;do echo $a && convert $a $a.jpg; done` - which converts the GIFs to JPGs and *Mathematica* imports them fine. But ideally there's be a native solution? Perhaps this question is far too specific.. :)

Comment: don't know whats wrong with the file, but the hang i think results from "gif.exe" ( which mathematica evidently uses ) hanging.

Comment: Kernel crashing is never an acceptable behaviour, you should report this to Wolfram Technical Support. "Help" > "Give feedback"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try constraining the execution time to something reasonable

```
TimeConstrained[Import[filename, "Elements"], 1]
```

this will abort the `Import` function after 1 second allowing you to skip the offending files.
A list of non-offending files can be obtained with this:

```
filelist = Select[FileNames["*.*"], (Length@TimeConstrained[Import[#, "Elements"], 1] > 0) &];
```